# How to change generator value with dbExpress framework whithout using stored procedures?

Tags: delphi, firebird, dbexpress

How to change a generator value with dbExpress framework? I want to change generator value directly with dbExpress, without writing a stored procedure in RDBMS side or etc. 
Please help me for doing that.

Comment: Can't you execute the [`ALTER SEQUENCE`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-alter-seq.html) command ?

Comment: Why do you want to change a generator value: in general it is a good way to screw things up in a database that is in active use.

Comment: In my app I want delete all records every days and then append new records to my table and refresh generator value (set to zero).

Comment: As generators are outside of transaction control that is not such a good idea unless you are absolutely sure there are non concurrent actions adding new records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK DBExpress don't have any class specialized in dealing with sequences/generators.

You still can use a standard TSQLQuery to instruct the dbEngine to alter a generator value, like this:

```
procedure TMyDataModule.RestartMyGenerator;
begin
  Q := TSQLQuery.Create;
  try
    Q.SQLConnection := MyConnection;
    //compatible with firebird 1.x and 2.x
    //Q.SQL.Text := 'set generator mygenerator to 0';  
    //better alternative, but compatible only with firebird 2.x
    Q.SQL.Text := 'alter sequence mygenerator restart with 0';
    Q.ExecSQL;
  finally
    Q.Free;
  end;
end;
```

(untested code, written directly in this window)

Answer (score 1):

Function with param **TableName** returns the next Generator value

```
function TDM.GenID(TableName: string): Integer;
var
  Qry: TSQLQuery;
begin
  Qry := TSQLQuery.Create(Self);
  try
    Qry.SQLConnection := SQLConnection;
    Qry.SQL.Add('SELECT GEN_ID(GEN_' + TableName + '_ID' + ', 1) ' +
                'FROM RDB$DATABASE');
    Qry.Open;
    Result := Qry.Fields[0].AsInteger;
  finally
    Qry.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Adjust the prodecure to your generators names

Comment: excuse me for poor english